# How to power array by array without loops

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays, array of numbers and array of exponents.

```
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4]
exponents = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to power vector by each element in exponents array and make and stack them vertically (create a matrix) without using loops or lambda's.
`np.power(vector, exponents)` doesn't work, it returns array with element wise power `[1, 2, 9, 64]`

Comment: `vector ** exponents[:, None]` assuming both are numpy arrays

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: The alternative would be `np.power.outer(vector, exponents)`

Comment: If your exponents happen to be a range 0,1,2,...,n-1 you can also use `np.vander(vector, n, True)`